Proving non-linear equations and inequalities involving rational numbers in Coq
I'm trying to formalize a stable-coin protocol using the Coq Interactive Theorem Prover. The proofs I have involve a lot of manipulation of linear and non-linear equations involving rational numbers. For now, I'm using the standard Coq library of rational numbers but it involves a lot of proof writing. I tried using tactics like 'nra' and 'lra' for finding proofs automatically but it gives me an error saying 'Tactic failure:  Cannot find witness'.
As an example, I was trying to prove this simple lemma using the proof given below.
Lemma test (qs : Q) (n : Q) (nu : Q) (ex : Q) :
  qs > 0 /\ n > 0 /\ nu > 0 /\ ex > 0 -> 
  qs <= ex -> qs / ex <= 1.
Proof.
    intros. lra.
Qed.

but it gave me an error saying 'Tactic failure:  Cannot find witness'. I tried destructing the rational numbers but couldn't complete the proof.
My questions are:

How to solve the above proof in the simplest way possible?
Are there any other libraries that would help me write simple proofs for inequalities and equations rational numbers and also automatically find proofs for simple lemmas as given above?
Are there examples of papers/code that deal with algebraic manipulations involving rational/real numbers?

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.
Hope you all have an amazing day!

If you destruct all rational numbers you should be able to simplify the goal to something that is entirely in terms of Z and positive, and then nia or lia may be able to solve it.

I know you are looking for an automated tactic, which I don't know about, but there are lemmas in the library, and it's important to know how to look for them with the Search command. You can query for patterns that occur in them, parts of their names etc. Very handy. I searched for theorems related with Search (_ %Q <= _ -> _). and Search (1 %Q * _).  (the %Q marks it as a Q type), and found two useful theorems. Removing the unused variables in your example gives this proof:
Require Import QArith.

Lemma foo (a b:Q) (H: 0 < b <= a): 1 <= a/b. 
    intros; apply Qle_shift_div_l; rewrite ?Qmult_1_l; apply H. 
Qed.


Your lemma test can likewise be proved with now intros; apply Qle_shift_div_r; rewrite ?Qmult_1_l.

I recommend using real numbers rather than rational numbers.  The former are better equipped with theorems and automatic tools, and the equality between real numbers is easier to use in mathematical proofs.

@Yves do you recommend any particular libraries for real numbers. Should I use the default real numbers library that comes with coq? Also inside definitions how can I compute stuff with real numbers?

In my experience, the default library of real numbers that comes with Coq is well suited for performing proofs about algebraic expressions in numbers and order relations.   I tried to reason about rational numbers, but I often discovered that there were much less lemmas about them that about real numbers.  On the other hand, exact computation with real numbers is only provided through the  ring tactic, but you also have approximate computation using the interval tactic.
